# For any sequence from Frechet spaces there exists a sequence that takes it to zero

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I am trying to prove following for Frechet spaces($X$):

Show that any sequence $(x_n) \subset X$ there exists a sequence $(\lambda_n)$ with $\lambda_n \neq 0$, $\lambda_n \downarrow 0$ such that $\lambda_n x_n \to 0$ in $X$.

But I don't really know how to start. I think need to show after $\exists N$ such that for $n>N$ $\lambda _n x_n$ is in a small neighborhood, but how to do this for any sequence from $X$. Or maybe there is a different way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The topology of a Frechet space is given by an increasing sequence of seminorms $\|\cdot\|_k$, and a sequence converges to $0$ if and only if $\|y_n\|_k \to 0$ for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Take $\lambda_n= \left(1+ n \max\lbrace\|x_1\|_n,\ldots,\|x_n\|_n\rbrace\right)^{-1}$. For $k\in\mathbb N$ and $n\ge k $ you then have $\|\lambda_n x_n\|_k \le \|\lambda_n x_n\|_n \le 1/n$.